# Is there a way to see the highest upvoted questions for a certain time interval?

Tags: discussion, tags, upvotes

If you visit the `Tags` link,you see the number of questions that has been posted below the tag link.Can we view the highest upvoted questions for a specific tag,for the current day?

Comment: Posts or Questions? With a bit of effort you can answer that yourself with [sede](http://data.stackexchange.com/) and pick one of the [MSE answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=tags+%5Bsede%5D) as a starting point.

Comment: highest upvoted currently, that was posted during a certain time period? or highest during that period not counting future votes.

Comment: With 10K tools you can see "extreme" votes for 1d, 2d, 1w, 2w, 1m at: http://stackoverflow.com/tools/

Comment: @Flexo 10K rep? you've given me much hope!

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a link or tab for this, but you can do this with search by using the `created` and `lastactive` search operators along side the `is:question` (this can be shortened to `is:q`) operator.

For instance, to see the highest voted questions tagged [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) for today, May 2nd 2016, you could use `[java] created:2016-05-02 is:q`. For the entire month of May, or as much of it as we've been through so far, you could use `[java] created:2016-05 is:q` and for this week, as in the past seven days, you could use `[java] created:2016-04-25..2016-05-02 is:q`

That's using created dates, and so will show posts created in those date ranges. If you want all *active* posts in that range, you can swap `created` with `lastactive` in the search parameters.

Once you've entered your search parameters, you can select the "votes" tab to sort your results by highest number of votes.

You can further narrow down your query with more tags, or using other search parameters listed in [the help center.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Keep in mind that this won't give you the scores from that specific timeframe, only the current timeframe. So if you were to use this search for, say, January of this year's top voted questions, some of them may have a higher score than they did at the end of January.